# Which dependency should be added for using the OpenCV FacemarkLBF?

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencv, intellij-idea

I was using [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dec/tutorial_facemark_usage.html) link tutorial to create the facemaker object. I already have added this dependency of OpenCV in my springboot build.gradle.kts file:-

```
implementation("org.openpnp:opencv:4.7.0-0")
```

I also tried to add this dependency:-

```
implementation("org.openpnp:opencv-contrib:4.7.0-0")
```

but it is not available. I got this :-

```
Could not find org.openpnp:opencv-contrib:4.7.0-0.
```

Comment: then it looks like the openpnp people don't build a package with contrib modules?